# Website Contact Form Not Sending Email

Tags: php, html, forms, email

So I recently uploaded my first website to an iPage server. The website runs perfectly with the exception of the Contact Form which for some reason refuses to send any email whatsoever from the form.
I use a PHP Script with the Post Method, and tried to fix my code multiple times to correct any error I might have entered, but so far to no avail. Here is the code:

HTML:
    <

```
form action = "js/mailer.php" form method="post" name="contactform" id="contactform" class="form validate item_bottom" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control required" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control required email" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control input-lg required" rows="9" placeholder="Enter Message"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <input type="submit" id="contactForm_submit" class="btn btn-trans btn-border btn-full" value="Submit">
                </div>
        </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$to = "aravindm3095@gmail.com";
$subject = "Hello Aravind!";

// data the visitor provided
$name_field = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email_field = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$comment = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

//constructing the message
$body = " From: $name_field\n\n E-Mail: $email_field\n\n Message:\n\n $comment";

mail($to, $subject, $body);

// redirect to confirmation
header('Location: confirmation.html');

} else {

echo "Failure";

}
?>
```

Can someone help me with this? It might be an error with my hosting server, or an error with my code. Your help is very much appreciated

Additional Comments: Followed the help provided (thank you for that) I made the necessary changes to the HTML and PHP, but the form is still not functional. It does not echo failure or redirect to the confirmation page, and upon inspecting the element with Firefox, I notice that upon hitting the submit button a subdivision appears under it saying "Sending....". But no email is sent, no message is echoed or page opened.

Comment: Your form tag is broken, it should look like:  

<form action="js/mailer.php" method="post" name="contactform" id="contactform" class="form validate item_bottom" role="form">

Comment: Also, let us know what it's doing. is it echoing failure?  is it going to confirmation.html but not sending mail?  Any specific errors displayed?  Anything in the logs?

Comment: You're repeating `form` Remove `form` from `form method="post"` Plus, for argument's sake, you have a missing `<` for `form action`

Comment: Your submit button isn't named also. Your conditional statement depends on it.

Comment: put `name="submit"` for submit tag

Answer (score 1):

From what i see in the code you posted, the PHP mailing script won't work as you are checking if a POST variable with the name 'submit' exists which it does not as in your form the submit button does not have a name attribute.
Try giving the submit button a name and put that name in the PHP if statement.

Comment: See my comment under Krish R's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Submit button name is missing in your form, You need to add name into your submit button,

```
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="contactForm_submit" class="btn btn-trans btn-border btn-full" value="Submit">
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

instead of

```
  <input type="submit" id="contactForm_submit" class="btn btn-trans btn-border btn-full" value="Submit">
```

Comment: It's not the only reason. OP has 2x `form` `form action = "js/mailer.php" form method="post"`

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML part should be something like below,

```
<form action = "js/mailer.php" method="post" name="contactform" id="contactform" class="form validate item_bottom" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control required" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control required email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control input-lg required" rows="9" placeholder="Enter Message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center">
        <input type="submit" name="sendemail" id="contactForm_submit" class="btn btn-trans btn-border btn-full" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

In above, I have added `name="sendemail"` in submit button.

And your PHP script that sends email should be like

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sendemail'])) { // <-- variable name changed

    $to = "aravindm3095@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Hello Aravind!";

    // data the visitor provided
    $name_field = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email_field = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $comment = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //constructing the message
    $body = " From: $name_field\n\n E-Mail: $email_field\n\n Message:\n\n $comment";
    $headers = "From: " . $email_field; // <-- Code added
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers); // <-- Code added

    // redirect to confirmation
    header('Location: confirmation.html');
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Failure";
}
?>
```

Comment: I made the above changes to the PHP and HTML sections but to no avail. The form does not echo failure or redirect to the confirmation page. 

When I inspect the element using Firefox, there's a subdivision that appears under the submit button div that says "Sending..." but that's all that occurs. No message is sent and form just appears stuck. 

Could it be a server problem?